# How can I fake OLEDB.OleDBDataAdapter to shim OleDBDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet) to shim results for unit testing using NUnit

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit, oledbconnection, microsoft-fakes

I have been working on a problem where I am unable to shim the `.Fill` method of the OLEDBDataAdapter.  I have written a function to query the DB to return a table of results.  If the query returns no results it is an error (and a valid one in the context of my function).

The function has been tested thoroughly and works fine.  The problem comes when I try to write a unit test to test this functionality.  In order to do it properly I need to shim the Fill method to return a dataset with a non empty list of data tables.  The shim function itself is very straightforward but I can't get it to be reached.

When I try to set a delegate for `OledDbDataAdapter.Fill` method the only fake object I have is `OleDbDataAdapter.FillDataSetObjectString` which is the correct function, but it only has one of the available overloads which I am not using.  I just want to be able to pass in a data set into the fill method, but the signature required for the delegate include an ADODB Record Set and source table name.  It would be a significant amount of refactoring to make use of those objects at this point and I would much rather be able to use the functioning production code AS-IS.

Please note that I have tried overloading the delegate and passing in empty objects or null references into the Fill method without any success.

Web searches have been very unhelpful to this point.  Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

As requested here is a sample of the relevant code,

```
Function GetTable(adapter as OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter,con As OleDb.OleDbConnection) as DataTable

dim selectCmd as OleDb.OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
sleectCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Table"
adapter.SelectCommand = selectCmd

dim ds as new DataSet
adapter.Fill(ds)

if ds.tables.count = 0 then
'Throw exception
End if

return ds.tables(0)
End Function
'
```

Here is the code that I use in my Unit Test,

```
Dim con As New OleDb.Fakes.ShimOleDbConnection()
con.CreateCommand = AddressOf ShimCreateCommand
Dim adapter As New OleDb.Fakes.ShimOleDbDataAdapter

adapter.FillDataSetObjectString = AddressOf ShimAdapterFill

Using dataStore As New DataStore()
    dataStore.GetTable(con, adapter)
End Using
```

Comment: Can you include sample code? It's an interesting question, but liable to closure if that's not present.

Comment: Please see my sample code now :)